# Trouble with overlay using MKPolyline & MKPolylineView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have added an overlay to my MKMapView using the addOverlay: method. The overlay was made using MKPolyline and stroked using MKPolylineView. The stroke color is blue, with an alpha value of 0.7.

When the view initially loads, the overlay is drawn correctly but the surrounding areas of the overlay are blue as well...
When I pinch & zoom out, the blue area is still there but it adjusts to my new zoom level. This is somewhat hard to describe... but basically I have a small rectangle of "normal map" trapped inside a larger rectangle that is blue.

It will disappear when I zoom out to view the entire country and when I zoom back in everything is normal.

I think this may be caused by me not implementing the MKOverlayProtocol correctly?

If anyone has any ideas please throw them my way...

EDIT:

Here is the code that creates the MKPolyline and the delegate method.

```
-(MKPolyline *)bluePolyline
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bluePoints[16];
    bluePoints[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.526483, -97.882454);
    bluePoints[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.526407, -97.887883);
    bluePoints[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.527244, -97.887905);
    bluePoints[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.527282, -97.887304);
    bluePoints[4] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.527577, -97.887304);
    bluePoints[5] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.527596, -97.885727);
    bluePoints[6] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.530194, -97.88577); //Seale St. &      Corrale Ave.
    bluePoints[7] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.530213, -97.883892); //Retama & Corral Ave.
    bluePoints[8] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.530279,-97.881907);
    bluePoints[9] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.530337,-97.880201);
    bluePoints[10] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.530356,-97.877959);
    bluePoints[11] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.52753,-97.877884); //West C Ave. & Armstrong
    bluePoints[12] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.527492,-97.878367); 
    bluePoints[13] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.527397,-97.878817);
    bluePoints[14] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.527349,-97.882454);
    bluePoints[15] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.526483, -97.882453);

    if(bluePolyline == nil)
    {
        bluePolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:bluePoints count:16];
    }
    bluePolyline.title = @"Blue Route";
    _bluePolyline = bluePolyline;
    return _bluePolyline;
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *aView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:(MKPolyline *)overlay];

//aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];

aView.lineWidth = 10;

return aView;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that creates and adds the MKPolyline and the viewForOverlay method?

Comment: Can you also attach screenshot?

Comment: So you have a `bluePolyline` method, a `bluePolyline` ivar, _and_ a `_bluePolyline` ivar?  The polyline coordinates and viewForOverlay look ok.  How are you calling the `bluePolyline` method and from where?

Comment: The `bluePolyline` is called from my "model". The name if my model is `MapBrain`. So I created an instance of my model in my View Controller like this `MapBrain *mapBrain` of course I "alloc" "init" as well. I then say `self.mapBrain.bluePolyline` and it returns a new MKPolyline if one does not exist already.

Comment: I think I MAY have fixed the problem. I never actually put the `MKOverlay` protocol in my viewController's header file.

It has worked flawlessly the last 10 builds... but I'm curious as to how `mapView:viewForOverlay:` was being called prior to me saying `@interface className : UIViewController <MKOverlay>`

Comment: The protocol declaration lets the compiler warn you about missing required methods or avoid warnings when trying to assign a delegate.  The actual delegate hookup is done by setting the delegate property.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina - so if that's true then I don't know what actually fixed the problem :/

I had set the delegate property to myself in the `viewDidLoad` method... am I correct in doing that?

Comment: I am having this exact same problem and I don't know why... I have set the maps delegate to myself in viewDidLoad and declared the MKOverlay protocol in my view controllers header file... Any ideas?!?!?

Comment: @Shredder2794 - Have you implemented the `MKOverlay` protocol?

This post is old so I can't remember exactly how I solved it but according to my comment above, I fixed it by implementing the protocol and the method `mapView:viewForOverlay:`.

I'll have to find this project and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I could definitely use it!

Comment: @Shredder2794 - I answered the question.

Good luck! If you need any help feel free to throw some code at me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing my problem by implementing the `MKOverlay` Protocol method:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay;
```

like so:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *aView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:(MKPolyline *)overlay];

    if(overlay.title == @"Blue Route")
    {
        aView.lineWidth = 7.0;
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    }
    if(overlay.title == @"Gold Route-A")
    {
        aView.lineWidth = 10.0;
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    }
    if(overlay.title == @"Gold Route-B")
    {
        aView.lineWidth = 7.0;
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    }
    return aView;
```

}

Where each overlay was created elsewhere in my model.

Comment: The problem is still occurring for me :( Is there a sample project or additional code that you could post?

Comment: That is the only code I had that could have produced the error.

If you want, ask a question on here and I will take a look at your code

Comment: I just discovered that it is a problem involving the users location. When I set MAPVIEW.showsUserLocation=false than the problem doesn't occur any more.

Comment: But most of the time won't you want to have the `mapView` show the users location? I never set mine to false :/

Comment: Exactly! At least now I know it has something to do with the users location annotation...